# Rust: Lifetime outliving anonymous function

Tags: rust

I'm trying to simulate an async execution with the function `spawn` but I fail to compile the   code snippet below.

```
use std::thread::{spawn, JoinHandle};

fn main() {
    let data  = vec![String::from("some data"), String::from("some more data")];

    let doer = Doer{f: |x| {return x + " hello"} };

    let results: Vec<JoinHandle<String>> = data.iter()
        .map(|x| doer.apply_async(x.to_owned()))
        .collect();

    results.iter().for_each(|x| println!("{}", x.join().unwrap()));
}

struct Doer {
    f: fn(xs: String) -> String
}

impl Doer {
    fn apply(&self, datum: String) -> String {
        let f = &self.f;
        return f(datum);
    }

    fn apply_async(&self, datum: String) -> JoinHandle<String> {
        return spawn(move|| self.apply(datum));
    }
}
```

I have an error like this `first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 25:5...`

I'm not sure to understand what lifetime is outliving the anonymous lifetime. 
Any idea?

Comment: Any argument provided to a Rust thread must have a static lifetime. You may use crossbeam if that is not an acceptable requirement. `doer` does not have a static lifetime, and that is your issue.

Comment: Even if you fix the above, using the following code, you will get another issue: `data` does not live long enough. You can solve this using crossbeam.

Answer (score 1):

`apply_async` is a method that takes `&self`. This means that `self` is a reference that is only guaranteed to live for the duration of the call to `apply_async`. The closure `move || self.apply(datum)` captures `self`, lifetime and all, which means it is not `'static`. This is why you can't call `spawn` on it.

If `Doer` implements `Clone`, one way to solve this problem is to make a clone of `*self` and `move` it into the closure.

```
    fn apply_async(&self, datum: String) -> JoinHandle<String> {
        let s = self.clone();
        return spawn(move || s.apply(datum));
    }
```

If you don't want to clone the whole `Doer`, you could only copy the necessary parts, and reimplement `apply` inside `apply_async`, for instance:

```
    fn apply_async(&self, datum: String) -> JoinHandle<String> {
        let f = self.f;
        return spawn(move|| f(datum));
    }
```